# JQuery UI sortable placeholder per panel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, placeholder

I have a problem in sortable option in JQuery Ui. for example I have multi `div` or `panel` (bootstrap) and each `div` have `custom height and width`. now I want to have placeholder base on each height and width.

```js
$(function () {
    $(".grid").sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 'invalid',
        placeholder: 'span2 well placeholder tile',
        forceHelperSize: true
    });
});
```

```css
.placeholder {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888;
}
.tile {
    height: 100px;
}
.grid {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row grid span8">
    <div class="well span2 tile">A</div>
    <div class="well span2 tile" style="height:500px;">B</div>
    <div class="well span2 tile" style="width:100px;">C</div>
    <div class="well span4 tile">D</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myimedia/Sm4EK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add the [`start` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start) in your sortable and update dimensions :

```
$(function () {
    $(".grid").sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        revert: 'invalid',
        placeholder: 'well placeholder tile',
        forceHelperSize: true,
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height())
            ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.width())
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm4EK/971/)